# rails ujs confirm fires another event if page reloaded

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I have a DBA maintenance page that has links to several task. Most of the links have a data-confirm event.

```
= link_to "Recompute Members Quotas",recompute_quotas_group_path(@group), 
class:"button small round",data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

These task may move to the model as business rules if preferences change, but for now this is more a less a test page.

When one of the task is completed, the controller redirects back to the maintenance page.

```
def recompute_quotas
  results = @group.recompute_members_quotas
  redirect_to maintenance_group_path(@group), notice:"Member Quotas Recomputed: #{results}."
end
```

The problem I'm seeing if I click on another button/link after a task has completed, the data-confirm dialog will display twice. Do another task and lick another button and you get three dialogs.

I assume the page is cached and each redirect/reload fires new confirm events.

Is there a way to force the old events to quit?

I tried adding an id to the link, but still fires multiple events for each object.

Comment: Are you using Turbolinks? My woes of this type often trace back to code that accidentally binds the JS events on every page "load".

Comment: Looks like Turbolinks. Though I'd try it again. I did add `data-no-turbolink="1"` to the pages main block and it seemed to stop to duplicate events.  I'll answer my own question after I checkout a few more things.

Comment: Upon further review! - data-no-turolinks does not stop duplicate events in all cases.  Will remover turbo links altogether and see if that is the problem.